# Android Native and AIR Application Communication

Tags: android, actionscript, air, flash-cs5

I am looking for a way to communicate between a Android application built using Adobe AIR and a native application. I know it is possible between two native applications using Intents or Remote methods. But is it possible to send a message to a native service from an Adobe AIR built application that doesn't have access to the native API?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I am aware of, since Air for Mobile is designed to be cross-platform.  It doesn't have much in the way of OS specific capabilities, that I know of.

Have you considered using Socket communication?

Comment: That was my initial thought. I was just interested in seeing if anyone knew of another way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use socket programming. I am using it.
You create a server socket on the native app and create a socket on the Air app. and connect them on 127.0.0.1